# NewRelic how to find out if a project uses it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, newrelic

I need to find out if any asp.net mvc applications use NewRelic. I passed all the references and did a text search with the object "NewRelic" but I didn't find any occurrences. Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic's APM agent is the one in charge of monitoring web apps. Assuming your app runs on Windows, you can check if the agent is installed in **Start > All Programs > New Relic .NET Agent**.
If there's no such menu, there is most likely no agent running.

Also, check if the following file exist in your code base **newrelic.config**.

As for New Relic's Browser agent (Real User Monitoring), take a look at the generated HTML of your web app, and if you spot the following string in the code `window.NREUM` it means that Browser is instrumented either manually (snippet in the HTML template, like Google Analytics) or automatically through the APM agent.

Source: [uninstallation docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/installation/uninstall-net-agent).